# Passing function to angular directive with a varying amount of parameters

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a function I want to pass to a directive. The directive is used in two places, however, and at the first place the function takes two parameters, the second place it only takes one parameter:

```
Function1(param1)

Function2(param1, param2)
```

I only have access to param1 in the directive. How do I modify Function2 so that it returns Function1? I have thought about changing the implementation of Function2 to the following:

```
Function2(param2) { 
 return function(param1) {
    //do something with param2
 }
```

}

And passing it to the directive like this:

```
 function="Function2(param2)"
```

However, this causes the Angular digest cycle to go into an infinite loop.  How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, i wouldn't use function as an attribute name, since it's a reserved word. You can add another attribute on the scope like: `function-params="[param1, param2]"`

so the element will look like this:

```
<my-directive func="myFunction" function-params="[param1, param2]"></my-directive>
```

Then, in the directive you'll call it using [apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply):

```
angular.module('app').directive('myDirective', {
  ...
  scope: {
     func: '=',
     functionParams: '='
  },
  link: function(scope){
      scope.func.apply(null, scope.functionParams);
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you, that's a lot more clean.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by using a workaround where I pass param2 into the directive scope, along with a boolean indicating whether the function passed into the directive is Function1 or Function2. If Function1, call the passed in function, let's call it passed_in_function, like this:

```
  passed_in_function(param1)
```

If Function 2, call it like this:

```
 passed_in_function(param1, param2)
```

Ugly, but works. I'm sure someone can provide a better solution though.